# Spark: Assigning Roles to Invited Users

Tags: laravel, roles, laravel-spark

Using Laravel Spark, is there a way to -- either via UI or programmatically -- assign a team role to an invited user?

That is, Laravel Spark doesn't allow admins to create users.  Instead, a owner user invites them.  This creates an entry in the invitations table, and sends an email URL to the potential user.  Users can then follow this URL, and sign up for a user account.  Once they've signed up, an admin can change their role via UI.

Laravel Spark lets you set a default role for all invited users.  What I want to know is: Does Laravel Spark provide a mechanism that would let me invite user A and have them end up with role B, and invite user C and have them end up with role D.

I can think of a number of ways to achieve this myself with custom code, but before I do that I want to know if this wheel's been invented.

Answer (score 0):

Spark Roles is useful as it will allow you to assign user roles/permissions as the user signs up and/or is assigned to a team. https://github.com/centrality-labs/spark-roles